# PHP $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']: How to preserve filename and extension?

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a doc file from a form and send it to email. I am using

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

The problem is, it is returning a randomly generated file name. So, when it reaches the inbox, the filename is phpvwRGKN.dat (filename is random each time).

How can I preserve the filename and extension?

Note: I am using [geekMail class](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/11/simpler-way-to-send-text-html-emails-with-attachments-in-php/)

Comment: dude print_r($_FILES);

Answer (score 53):

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` will contain the temporary file name of the file on the server.  This is just a placeholder on your server until you process the file

`$_FILES['file']['name'];` contains the original name of the uploaded file from the user's computer.

Comment: $geekMail->attach('/home/willem/file2.zip') should be the format to use the library.

So I had to use
$attachment = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$geekMail->attach($attachment);

Is there a way I can pass ['name'] as well along with the path?

Comment: If you create a img with a src of tmp_name, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! Couldn't find that information anywhere on the web

Comment: Ya! Not to much documentation about that.

Comment: I have found that `$_FILES['file']['name']` is **url encoded**. So if I upload `Script for "Star Wars".pdf` then `$_FILES['file']['name']` will be `Script for %22Star Wars%22.pdf`. You might want to use `urldecode()` to get the original name accurately.

Answer (score 10):

`$_FILES["file"]["name"] - the name of the uploaded file`

from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: If I use $_FILES["file"]["name"] and assign it to a variable, say $attachment, than it will not work because, that returns just a file name. I think I'll need to give the path and path can come only from tmp_name. 

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Most mail libraries have two filenames you use for attachments. One is the name/location of the file on the server, the other is the name as you want the user to see it. In your case, the name/location is `tmp_name`, and the end-user filename is `name`.

Comment: From your question I understand that you want to store the file on the server, by using the name instead of tmp_name. The thing to do is use http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php `move_uploaded_file()` and move the `tmp_file` to its permanent path with `name` filename.

Comment: No, I want to send the file in an email not upload to server.

Comment: Then, you can `rename($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"])` it...

Answer (score 5):

`$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` contains the actual copy of your file content on the server while
`$_FILES["file"]["name"]` contains the name of the file which you have uploaded from the client computer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, but you might try the Pear Mail_Mime class instead.

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs

Otherwise you can use a bit of code. Gabi Purcaru method of using rename() won't work the way it's written. See this post https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#97347 . You'll need something like this:

```
$dir = dirname($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$destination = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
rename($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
$geekMail->attach($destination);
```

Comment: Never uses the original user input `$_FILES["file"]["name"];` as the real destination on your filesystem, or else you are up to a good headache at best.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Gabi Purcaru mentions above, the proper way to rename and move the file is to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). It performs some safety checks to prevent security vulnerabilities and other exploits. You'll need to sanitize the value of `$_FILES['file']['name']` if you want to use it or an extension derived from it. Use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)`($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` to safely get the extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get the uploaded file name, use `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

But If you wanna read the uploaded file you should use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`, because tmp_name is a temporary copy of your uploaded file and it's easier than using

`$_FILES["file"]["name"] // This name includes a file path, which makes file read process more complex`