# AJAX file upload not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Having an issue with file upload in ajax. There are two pages:

- index.php
- insert.php

**ajax code below-**

```
             var file= $('input[name=fileName').prop('files')[0];

             var fileName=file.name;

            var fData = {
                'category' : $('input[name=category]').val(),
                'itemValue' : $('input[name=itemValue]').val(),
                'quantity' : $('input[name=quantity]').val(),
                'location' : $('input[name=location]').val(),
                'comment' : $('input[name=comment]').val(),
                'fileName' : fileName

            };
            console.log(fData);
            //process the form
            $.ajax({
                url: "iItem.php",
                type: "POST",                   
                async: true,
                data: fData,
                success:function(data){

                }
            });
```

My question is `how can get the $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'] in insert.php` page?

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Read the question again please.

Comment: @FrankM i seriously did not get what the error is... did you?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I think there is no error, but he is just asking how to get the `tmp_name` in the `fileName` var.

Comment: probably [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945330/php-filestmp-name) would help if that's the case.

Comment: `var fileName=file.name;` why i think this will send file name only that's why it is not working try  this`var fileName=file;`

Comment: youre requesting iItem.php, wich doesnt exist in your description...

Comment: @Jonasw I think that is the problem.

Comment: @codenut: so you did copy+paste and youre wondering why it isnt working?????

Comment: this not my question

Comment: for upload a file it must need in php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , so my question is how can I get the tmp_name ?
hope you got my point.

Comment: @Mdimran You are only sending the file name, as codenut already mentioned. You have to upload the actual file. Find a tutorial on how to upload files via ajax, there are plenty.

Comment: @Mdimran secondly, you are sending the file to `iItem.php`. You can only access the `$_FILES` variables from that script (or any script files included by that script). I say this because in the question you mention wanting to access it in `insert.php`. That's a totally different script, you aren't sending the file details there. So unless `insert.php` is mentioned in an include/require statement in `iItem.php`, then `insert.php` won't even run, never mind have the $_FILES variables accessible to it.